# any help or idea appreciated, Left Join Calculation DAX POWER BI

Tags: currency

i have one sales fact table, one product table and one table for the exchange rates with direct query from sql server 2014.
sales fact table and product table have three different currencies.  and also products purchased different currencies.

but, i could not able to solve how to put an if condition,cause right now i just manage to find the costs with all different currencies. but actually i need to have a calculation like this:

ıf product purchase currency = "USD" or "EUR"  then lookup the exchange rate table for the related sale date, take the currency, but if it is local currency, just leave it. the i try var with the measure and calculate it works but have some inconsistencies.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5gSx.png

```
SUMX( 
PRODUSTEXCHANGEFACTTABLE,
PRODUSTEXCHANGEFACTTABLE[quantıty] * 
LOOKUPVALUE('exrate'[Value],
            'exrate'[Date],PRODUSTEXCHANGEFACTTABLE[Date],
             exrate[currency],PRODUSTEXCHANGEFACTTABLE[currency])           
*
 RELATED ( 'product'[purchasefıyat] ) 
 
)    
 
     
COst Products = 
VAR tl =

CALCULATE ( 
    [totalpurchase(multiple currency)], 
    STOK[GIRPCNS] = "L" 
    )
VAR USD = 

CALCULATE ( 
    [totalpurchase(multiple currency)], 
    STOK[GIRPCNS] = "D" 
    )  
VAR USD_tl = 
 SUMX( 
     STOKHAR,
LOOKUPVALUE('KUR'[Value],
            'KUR'[Date],STOKHAR[Date],
             KUR[kod],STOKHAR[DOVKOD])           
* USD
 )

VAR E=
CALCULATE ( 
    [totalpurchase(multiple currency)], 
    STOK[GIRPCNS] = "E" 
    )  
VAR E_tl= 
 SUMX( 
        STOKHAR,
LOOKUPVALUE('KUR'[Value],
            'KUR'[Date],STOKHAR[Date],
             KUR[kod],STOKHAR[DOVKOD])    
 * E
 )

 return 

COALESCE(USD_tl,E_tl,tl)
```

Comment: finally  i got it, i even did not know that i can use + for var. but it worked. 
VAR USD = 
SUMX(
    FILTER(
        STOKHAR,
        RELATED(STOK[GIRPCNS]) = "D") ,
        STOKHAR[MIKTAR]* RELATED(STOK[GIRFIYAT]) * LOOKUPVALUE('KUR'[Value],
            'KUR'[Date],STOKHAR[Date],
             KUR[kod],STOKHAR[DOVKOD]))